# Is a pathwise-continuous function continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a locally connected and simply connected space and $f:X\to Y$ is a function such that for every path $\phi:[a,b]\to X$ the composition $f\circ\phi$ is continuous. Does it follow that $f$ is continuous? Here is a proof using countable choice if we additionally assume that $X$ is first-countable and locally path connected:

Assume that $f$ is not continuous at $x\in X$, and let $(U_n)$ be a local base at $x$ which forms an inclusion chain $U_{n+1}\subseteq U_n$. Then there is a neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ and a sequence of points $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\in U_n$ and $f(x_n)\notin V$. Let $\phi_n:[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n]\to U_n$ be a path from $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$, and take $\phi$ to be the union of these, extended to $[0,1]$ by setting $\phi(0)=x$. Now $\phi$ is continuous on $(0,1]$ by the pasting lemma, and it is continuous at $0$ because every neighborhood of $x$ contains some $U_n\supseteq \phi([0,\frac1n])$.

Thus $\phi$ is a path, so $f\circ\phi$ is continuous, and then there is an $n$ such that $f\circ \phi([0,\frac1n])\subseteq V$, which is a contradiction because $f\circ \phi(\frac1n)=f(x_n)\notin V$.

Is it necessary to assume first-countability here? If it helps, the application I want to use this theorem for is the claim that a covering map $p:Y\to Z$ lifts paths $f:X\to Z$ uniquely (given a basepoint $p(y_0)=f(x_0)$) to $\tilde f:X\to Y$ when $X$ is simply connected and locally connected. If I define $\tilde f$ such that $\tilde f(x)=\tilde \phi(1)$ for any path $\phi:[0,1]\to X$ from $x_0$ to $x$ (I have already shown that liftings exist for $X=[0,1]$ and $X=[0,1]^2$), then I can show that this defines a function which is "pathwise continuous" in the sense above, and I want to conclude that $\tilde f$ is the desired (continuous) lifting.

Comment: I suspect you can get a counterexample by taking $X$ to be (in [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29) terminology) the "extended long ray", which is the one-point compactification of the long ray.  Then take $Y = \{0,1\}$ and $f(\infty) =1$, $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.  If I recall correctly, there aren't any nontrivial paths to $\infty$, so this function is pathwise continuous, but clearly not continuous.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That almost works, but it is not simply connected (it is not even path-connected).  You can make it work by adjoining a path from $\infty$ to some other point.

Comment: Your argument in the first-countable case requires $X$ to be locally path connected, not just locally connected.  For the application in the final paragraph, you need to use the fact that $p$ is locally a homeomorphism (and locally $\tilde{f}$ looks like $p^{-1}\circ f$).

Comment: @EricWofsey: Oops, you're right.  Or maybe another way to achieve the same thing is to take the open long ray (i.e. with 0 removed) and take the one-point compactification of that?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Sure (that will in fact be homeomorphic to what you would get by adjoining a path from $0$ to $\infty$).

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah, yes that would be a counterexample. You need to fix the function so that it is continuous along the path to $\infty$, for example $f(x)=\frac1{x+1}$ on the initial copy of $\Bbb R^+$ and $f(x)=0$ for the other copies (and $f(\infty)=1$).

Comment: @EricWofsey Could you put your hint about $p^{-1}\circ f$ into an answer? I've been hitting my head on that for a while now and it doesn't seem quite so simple. (The problem is in showing that there is a neighborhood $x\in U$ such that $f[U]$ is contained in an evenly covered neighborhood $V$, by some sort of connectedness; after that the local homeomorphism property can show that $f$ is continuous at $x$ by continuity of $p^{-1}\restriction p[V]$.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Such a $U$ exists by continuity of $f$ (for any neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f[U]\subseteq V$).  If you want more details on this, I suggest you ask a separate question--it wouldn't really be an answer to the question you asked here.

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry, I meant that we need to show $\tilde f[U]\subseteq V$ for some evenly covered neighborhood $V$. As suggested, I have expanded on the exact difficulty in a [separate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1353471/50776), and if you have a good idea then please make it known there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comments, this is not true without some additional hypotheses on $X$.  For instance, let $L=[0,\omega_1]$ be the closed long line and let $X=L/\{0,\omega_1\}$.  This is locally connected and simply connected (any path must be contained in $[0,\alpha]$ for some $\alpha<\omega_1$, and $[0,\alpha]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and hence contractible).  Let $Y=[0,\omega_1)$ and let $f:X\to Y$ send the equivalence class $\{0,\omega_1\}$ to $0$ and every other point to itself.  Note that $f$ is not continuous, because $f^{-1}([0,1))$ is not open (it doesn't contain a neighborhood of $\omega_1$).  However, for every path $\phi:[a,b]\to X$, $f\circ \phi$ is continuous, since the image of $\phi$ must be contained in $[0,\alpha]$ for some $\alpha<\omega_1$ and $f$ is continuous on any such $[0,\alpha]$.